# label a sequence of plots with letters using lapply

Tags: r

I have a small function that creates a cumulative distribution plot that I run on a dataset using lapply (dataset is a list broken down by analyte). I would like the function to label the plots "a)" through "g)", but can't seem to figure out how to get lapply to generate the sequential lettering. Any ideas? Code below.

```
cdf.int <- function(data.set) {
  plot(ecdf(log10(data.set$CONC_CALC)), main = "", xlim = c(-3.0, 3.0))
  text(-4, 1.2, "a)", xpd = TRUE)
}

pdf(paste("output/figures/CDF_RegionalData.pdf", sep = ""), 
  height = 11, width = 8)
par(las = 1, omi = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0), mfrow = c(5, 2), ps = 10, family = "sans", mar = c(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0))
lapply(split.rd, cdf.int) 
dev.off()
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `for` loop? I think it would be a more natural choice here, because you don't need a return value.

Comment: Definitely could do that and that was my first instinct. I've been trying to move towards using the apply functions, rather than using a for loop. I might just do that to get through this, but am still interested in if there is a solution to this using lapply. It would simplify my code in the future as developing series of plots is pretty typical in my work.

Comment: There is no reason to shun `for` loops. They have their place. Of course you could do `lapply(seq_along(split.rd), modifiedFunction)`, where the modified function uses the index, but that's just a `for` loop made more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

this works like a dream

```
cdf.int <- function(n) {
  plot(rnorm(10), main = paste0(letters[n], ")"), xlim = c(-3.0, 3.0))
  text(-4, 1.2, "a)", xpd = TRUE)
}

pdf("test.pdf", height = 11, width = 8)
par(las = 1, omi = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0), mfrow = c(5, 2), ps = 10, family = "sans", mar = c(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

lapply(1:6, cdf.int) 
dev.off()
```

A (just a little) more realistic example using `mapply`

```
ll <- list(a=rnorm(10),
           b=rnorm(10))

cdf.int <- function(data, name) {
  plot(data, main = name, xlim = c(-3.0, 3.0))
  text(-4, 1.2, "a)", xpd = TRUE)
}

pdf("test.pdf", height = 11, width = 8)
par(las = 1, omi = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0), mfrow = c(2, 1), ps = 10, family = "sans", mar = c(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0))

mapply(cdf.int, ll, names(ll)) 
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the an example of the downside of using `lapply/sapply` ... the names of list elements do not get passed to the function, only the values do. So you can get around that when using `lapply` by working with `names(yourlist)` (or perhaps `1:length(yourlist)`) and pulling from 'yourlist' with :

```
  lapply(names(yourlist), function(x){ plot( yourlist[[x]] } )
```

In your case that does mean you will need to rewrite your function.